# How Do I Find Consecutive Values

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

Let´s assume I have this vector:

```
x <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

I want to find the amount of times we have ¨1¨ 3 consecutive times.
For this I am using this code-

```
n.hot <- which(df, df$vector = 1,1,1)
```

What can I do to make it actually work? 
Thank you

Comment: What is your desired output? Also, if you have 4 1's in a row, does it count once or twice (i.e., all matches with 3 consecutive, or at least 3 consecutive)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case `1 1 1 1` means for you that `1 1 1` actually appears twice, you could do:

```
sum(stats::filter(x, c(1, 1, 1), circular = TRUE, sides = 2) == 3)

[1] 7
```

Answer (score 3):

One option could be:

```
sum(with(rle(x), lengths[as.logical(values)]) == 3)

[1] 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the rolling sum and if it equals 3, you know it's what you want.

```
library(zoo)

x <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)

threetogether <- rollsum(x, 3, fill = NA, align = "right")

threetogether == 3
```

Output:

```
 [1]    NA    NA FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Suggest using `rollsumr` with r on the end in place of `align = "right"` and also `fill = 0` so that the first two elements become FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another (less conventional) idea,

```
sum(tapply(x, cumsum(x != 1), FUN = length) == 4)
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly three consecutive 1's or if you want at least three consecutive ones, here is a function using base R solution that utilizes `cumsum()` (and `diff()`. This just offsets the `cumsum` vector to compare if there are `n` consecutive ones. Right now it is designed to work with logical vectors or 0/1 vectors. And, if you have `"at least"` as type it will select the first match, but it is easily adaptable to select the last if you wanted.

```
consecutive_n <- function(vector, n, type = c("equal", "at least")) {

  length_vec <- length(vector)
  cumsum_vec <- cumsum(vector)

  difference <- cumsum_vec - c(rep(0, n), cumsum(vector)[-c((length_vec-n+1):length_vec)]) == n

  type <- match.arg(type)

  if(type == "equal") {
    difference & c(0, diff(difference)) == 1
  } else {
    difference
  } 

}

consecutive_n(x, 3)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
sum(consecutive_n(x, 3))
[1] 4
which(consecutive_n(x, 3))
[1]  5 10 14 21

sum(consecutive_n(x, 3, type = "at least"))
[1] 7
which(consecutive_n(x, 3, type = "at least"))
[1]  5  6 10 14 15 16 21
```

**Data**:

```
x <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```